# plugin jQuery file from local Pc into Html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

//the jQuery file and the location

```
<script src="C:/xampp/htdocs/AnasCourse/BootStarp/jQ.js"></script>
```

//i even tried this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/AnasCourse/BootStarp/jQ.js"></script>
```

// Simple code in jQ.js file :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  })
</script>
```

//and the result from the Console is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You dont need the script tags in JQ.js file. And also you need to include the jquery library in your html . <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: 1.it's was wrong when i wrote the script tags in the JQ and when i include the jquery library its work but based on the library that's i added.

2.I want another jquery file and modify on it beside on what i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

I think you not include the jQuery file first.

Comment: i did but i want another  jQuery file and modify on as i want

Comment: I not get properly what you want. If there is any conflict use noConflict.

Comment: Now it's worked thanks so much
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\xampp\htdocs\AnasCourse\BootStarp\js\j.js"></script>